# Can I make an inductor rated 75mH 40A from an induction motor?

Tags: inductor, induction-motor

For my test bench, I am trying to implement an inductor that meets the requirements below.  I have tried to purchase it outright as a made-up item, or the parts to make it (core and windings), but have had no luck finding what I need "off the shelf".

So I wondered: could this be done with a common standard induction motor?  I searched several catalogs of three-phase induction motors, but could not find the data presented in a way that translates to the requirements I need for (a) inductance and (b) AC current rating.

I seek guidance on how to interpret the data presented in a typical AC motor datasheet to extract the inductance and current rating.  Here is a typical motor datasheet (5.5kW 415V 3-phase):-

https://www.weg.net/catalog/weg/CI/en/Electric-Motors/Low-Voltage-IEC-Motors/General-Purpose-/Cast-Iron-TEFC-/W22-%28Cast-Iron%29/W22-IE1-5-5-kW-2P-132S-3Ph-380-400-415-660-690-V-50-Hz-IC411---TEFC---B3T/p/14231405

The ideal inductor for my bench will have the following characteristics:-

1. Inductance value required: L=75mH (+/-10%)
2. Impedance at 50Hz: 23.56ohms (calculated from X=2πfL, with L=75mH)
3. Maximum current: 40A (RMS) at a frequency of 20Hz.  Note that the current will be limited by the maximum voltage applied (from a VSD, hence the 20Hz).
4. VA rating@50Hz: 37.7kVA (calculated from V=23.56Ω.40A, I=40A, VA=V.I).
   The actual VA for the use-case at 20Hz will be much less (2/5 of this,
   or 15.1kVA).

Please note, of course, that an inductor only has two terminals.  To achieve this with a 3-phase induction motor, we could connect the inductors leads to any of the following:
(a) just one winding, or
(b) first connect two or even three motor windings in **series**, then connect the inductor leads to the remaining unconnected outer two terminals;
(c) first connect two or three motor windings in **parallel**, then connect the inductor leads.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 40 A is going to be a problem as a 5.5 kW motor is nowhere near that. Get a large enough laminated core, perhaps salvaged from a large transformer, and wind it yourself?

Comment: I get 120 J peak stored energy - enough to kill. Synchronous machines are used to provide capacitive or inductive reactive power in power grids - but that's three-phase (?).

Comment: A motor is a rotating transformer, not an inductor. If you're willing to modify one, you could either cut off the squirrel cage from an induction rotor, or remove the rotor entirely; both options will drastically alter the parameters of the unit, and I seriously doubt you'll find such ratings among most motors anyway (75mH 40A is almost 1kV at 50Hz!). Contact a local magnetics supplier and have them design a custom unit; it will not be cheap.

Comment: You *can* buy a [20 A rated 50 mH inductor](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/hammond-manufacturing/195R20/455524) as a standard off-the-shelf part. Two of those in parallel would give you a 40 A 25 mH inductor, and three of those in series makes a 40 A 75 mH inductor. The total cost, however, comes to nearly US$5,000, so it's not a cheap solution.

Comment: I have a sneaking suspicion it would be cheaper to hack the VSD to synthesize an inductive source impedance in the first place, and choose one with enough excess capacity to handle the full VAs, preferably one that's easy to hack as well. This would be an extended software project, but you might find someone willing to do it (or indeed have the experience to do it yourself).

Comment: @Hearth  Thanks, yes I was aware of the Hammond inductors/chokes, the one you mentioned is a beast: weighs 72lb (32.7kg) and costs over $1,300.  And I would need six in total, so that's 196kg and $7.8k (!) || Also, my application is AC excitation, and one of the notes on 195-196 series datasheet states: "For AC applications 60 Hz to 10,000 Hz try our 197 Series".  I **might** get away with it since the excitation frequency is rather low, 20Hz.  I checked the 197 series, the heaviest unit there is rated 25mH at 5A, 15mH at 10A DC bias.  https://www.hammfg.com/files/parts/pdf/197M5.pdf

Comment: @TimWilliams  Unfortunately, I need a **physical** inductor since this is part of a test bench to test something similar to what you described (synthesised inductor using a VSD).

Comment: LOL! Fair enough :)

Comment: @winny  Thanks, yes, the "5.5kW" was just used as an example of a motor datasheet - even that unit weighs 58kg, so I suspect what I need will be far heavier.

Comment: Given that a commercial offering weighs in at 200kg it seems unlikely you’ll get the same performance out of anything significantly smaller, although rewinding a mahoosive motor core might be a cheaper option if you can get hold of something suitable.

Comment: @TimWilliams "A motor is a rotating transformer, not an inductor." Yes, agreed - hence my question, I seek to understand how to interpret the typical motor datasheet to extract what it may be capable of in terms of being an inductor.  Leaving the motor intact, it would be interesting to see how its behaviour as an inductor is affected by the physical loading: shaft loading, speed, etc.

Comment: @TimWilliams  "Contact a local magnetics supplier" yes, thanks, already done that, and you're right, not cheap - plus long lead times, over 12 weeks in most cases.  Do you have any suppliers that you could recommend, perhaps?

Comment: I don't think you want to leave the motor intact... a coupled, rotating mass provides a terribly history-dependent variation in terminal impedance, not to mention windage loss causes resistance.  If you cut off the shorting bars, I expect the saturation current will be too low, and too high (too low inductivity) if you remove the rotor entirely, but you could still machine faces off it to increase its reluctance a modest amount while locked at a particular angle.

Comment: @FabioBarone Afraid I don't have any suppliers you would likely be interested in; shipping from USA to AU isn't going to be pretty.